# Retrofit for android @Multipart remove default headers

Tags: java, android, rest, multipartform-data, retrofit2

Making a @Multipart request adds these default headers (Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type) for each part, is there any way to remove them?

```
//REQUEST BODY
--25d35373-d2c3-46a3-969f-f5a1fd5f781a 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary <-- remove this one
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 <-- remove this one
Content-Length: 34
"40ccfee680a844780a41fbe23ea89934"
//
```

NOTE: I do not have access to the server so there is no way I will be able to make the server accept these headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build multipart body by your self in this way (kotlin code but same idea may be expressed with java):

```
val mpart = MultipartBody.Builder()
            .addFormDataPart("param", paramValue)
            .addPart(null, someRequestBody).build() // <-- (*) see explanation below

//thus, service method should looks like this:
@POST("upload/endpoint")
fun upload(@Body parts: MultipartBody)
```

(*) - this is the `addPart(headers: Headers, reqBody: RequestBody)` method, when you pass `null` to headers arg this removes all headers except `Content-Length:`

Comment: Thanks alot, this did solve the problem. the .addPart(null, someRequestBody) was not necessary tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST(...)
suspend fun updateImage(@Body Body: RequestBody): Response<ResponseBody>
```

```
val uploadFile = File(...)
val bodyFile = uploadFile.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaType())

val bodyBuilder = MultipartBody.Builder()
bodyBuilder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
bodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("img", uploadFile.name, bodyFile)

api.updateImage(bodyBuilder.build())
```

retrofit + coroutine