# How to upload a file without his header and container on Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am trying to upload a file to a server using retrofit2 Library. I don't want the file to be surrounded by any header or any container, I just want to send the raw file to the server.

I am using this interface :

```
    @PUT("JCExecPut/{typeUpload}/{fileId}")
    @Headers("Content-Type: image/jpeg")
    @Multipart
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile(@Path("typeUpload")Integer typeUpload, @Path("fileId")String fileId, @Part RequestBody image);
```

My upload function :

```
public void uploadFileToServer(File file) {

        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mediaTypeString), file);

        String idToUpload = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadFile(11, idToUpload, requestFile);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                // Success
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                // Failure
            }
        });
    }
```

The thing is that the server will always get a file instanciate like this

```
--ee3468c-eb4b-ff4-b59c-e09b08a4a25e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 46230
...
data image
...
--ee3468c-eb4b-ff4-b59c-e09b08a4a25e--
```

The way the server works needs only the data image, not all the containers data `--~~~---, content-disposition, etc`

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: have to use @Multipart annotaion. and  Multipart body request.

Comment: Out of curiosity but why would you not want to send these headers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914802/3999808

Comment: @Zun The server isn't made to handle those headers when we send a file.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

(answering here for the lost souls like me)

So I got this working like this,

1) Set the retrofit like this

```
@PUT
fun uploadFile(
    @Url url: String,
    @Header("Auth") authHeader: String = "IF_ANY",  // note theres no need to mention content headers
    @Body file: RequestBody
): Observable<ResponseBody>
```

2) Attaching file from your code

```
val requestFile = file.asRequestBody(YOUR_MEDIA_TYPE)
```

3) just call your method with the API **url** and **file**   // uploadFile(API_URL, requestFile)

I hope it saves someone hours of struggle

Comment: note I was struggling with Azure blob upload where it requires